# Value constructors in haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, nlp-question-answering, value-constructor

I have a question about Haskell. I'm new so I don't understand too well, but if anyone could help me I'd really appreciate. I have this exercise from a book that I bought.

> Create a type *Question* with value contructors *Sim* or *Nao*. Make a
>   function that:

- listQuest: receive from a parameter a list of *Questions* and return *0* for *Nao* or *1* for *Sim* corresponding the constructors in the list.

I tried this code:

```
module Question where 

data Question = Yes | No deriving Show

questNum :: Question -> Int
questNum No = 0
questNum Yes = 1

listQuest :: [Question] -> [Int]
listQuest listQuestion =  [ questNum quest | quest <- listQuestion ]
```

I'm lost in the prompt matter. Don't know what to write to use the function.

Thanks for the help

Comment: So what doesn't work for you exactly?

Comment: Haskell won't translate between English and... Portuguese? You have to use `Yes` and `No` as defined by the `data` declaration. (Or change to `data Question = Sim | Nao deriving Show`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm having trouble with the prompt too. I don't know what to write on it

Comment: Thanks, chepner, I didn't pay attention

Comment: @Marrows Check my edited answer please, add your promp issue with details in the question, you can edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, you did it by list comprehension, another way is using map:

```
listQuest :: [Question] -> [Int]
listQuest xs = map questNum  xs
```

shorter

```
listQuest :: [Question] -> [Int]
listQuest  = map questNum
```

using foldr (it is also a way to say map, indeed you can write the general map using foldr):

```
listQuest :: [Question] -> [Int]
listQuest = foldr (\x rs -> questNum x : rs) []
```

and the old good pattern matching (is map, but with pattern matching):

```
listQuest :: [Question] -> [Int]
listQuest []  = []
listQuest (x:xs) = questNum x : listQuest xs
```

your way, and all of this, are equivalent.

> On the prompt:

Then on the prompt you type something like:

```
$> :l file_name.hs
$> listQuest [Yes, Yes, No]
$> [1,1,0]
```